# X_transformed_fit_ attribute error: AttributeError: 'KernelPCA' object has no attribute 'X_transformed_fit_'

Tags: scikit-learn, pca, matrix-decomposition

I am trying to obtain which features in my dataset affects the principal components, and trying to observe how my data fitted in my Kernel PCA algorithm. 
I tried to use X_transformed_fit_ attribute which exists in documentary but I got this error: AttributeError: 'KernelPCA' object has no attribute 'X_transformed_fit_'

My code for KPCA is below:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import KernelPCA
kpca = KernelPCA(n_components = 2, kernel = 'cosine', fit_inverse_transform = False)
X = kpca.fit_transform(X)
kpca.X_transformed_fit_
```

If it is not the way I can obtain how to interpret the composition of my KPCA, then how am I going to understand that these principal components are constructed?
The reason why I am investigating is that I will continue to this process with clustering algorithm implementation (K-means, agglomerative HC), and I want to understand the characters of my distinct clusters that will be derived from the algorithms at the end (by understanding the structure of the principal components).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute `X_transformed_fit_` is only available when you set the parameter `fit_inverse_transform` to `True`.

Try:

```
kpca = KernelPCA(n_components = 2, kernel = 'cosine', fit_inverse_transform = True)
X = kpca.fit_transform(X)
kpca.X_transformed_fit_
```

Comment: could you tell what is the exact purpose of assigning X_transformed_fit_ at kpca? because it changes the computation results of eigenvalues and eigenvectors a lot. @Vivek Kumar

Comment: @Beg I'm sorry I dont know that. You may ask this on scikit-learn mailing list